# Understanding when the entropy $H(f(X))=0$?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I've been trying to understand this for a while now, but can't seem to get it. This question only refers to a discrete random variable X and some function $f$ in $\mathbb{R}$.
I've been told that $f(X)$ being an injective function is enough for the statement to hold.

But isn't $H(f(X)) = H(X)$ if the function is injective? This says nothing about the entropy being $0$. I would have assumed that it is only equal to $0$ if the function is injective **AND** the random variable already has $0$ entropy.

Am I completely off track here?

Comment: What's true is that $H(X \mid f(X)) = 0$ if $f$ is injective.

Comment: I thought that only $H(f(X)|X) = 0$ if $f$ is injective? Or are both correct?

Comment: $H(f(X)|X) = 0$ is true for any function (you don't need injectivity). If $X$ is known, then there is no uncertainity about $f(X)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're right, since if $f$ is injective, it can't change the probability density of the new random variable $Y = f(X)$. Are you sure the questions asks $f$ to be injective?

For a simple counterexample, let $f(x) = x$. Now, $H(f(X)) = H(X)$, an if $H(x) \neq 0$, then $H(f(X)) \neq 0$

Comment: Thank you, the question doesn't specify what $f$ should be but my uni colleagues that it should for the equality to hold. It just didn't make sense to me that this should be enough, but your answer clarified it, thanks!